# PostgreSQL should return both count and rows within a single statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that stores entries along with their timestamp. My node.js API should return both the count of rows and count of entries grouped by hour.

example:

```
{
    "count":"6",
    "countByHour":[
        "00":"1",
        "08":"2",
        "16":"3"
    ]
}
```

What should be the SQL query to generate this result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping sets for that, e.g.:

```
SELECT hour, COUNT(*) FROM hours GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((hour), ()) 
ORDER BY hour NULLS FIRST
```

This will return results like:

```
 hour | count
------+-------
      | 6
   00 | 1
   08 | 2
   16 | 3
```